# 200A Upgrade Main Panel Requirements

Tags: electrical-panel, solar, surge-suppression

I'm upgrading my old 100A panel [combined Meter and Load Center] to a new 200A Panel. Based on the panel location, and since I don't want to re-wire the entire house, I'm looking for a Combined 200A Meter & Load Panel which meets the requirements below.
Current panel is on the outside wall by the Living Room - flipping it to face inside would place it on the Living Room wall which may not be pretty.

Hoping someone has a panel to recommend.

- 200 AMP Main - Meter and Load Center Combination  -
- 14.5” Width - fits between 16” joists
- OUTDOOR RATED [Flush Mount Preferred, Surface Mount acceptable]
- OVERHEAD FEED
- MINIMUM 20 spaces
- COPPER Bus [willing to pay more for quality]
- CA Title 24 Compliant - [Separate Solar input]
- Support for BOTH 100 Amp Sub Panel AND Support whole house [panel] surge protector
- EUSERC Complaint [my POCO is PGE so EUSERC compliance seems like a requirement]

Note: Prefer Siemens brand as they're likely to be around longer than I will be so I won't risk not being able to replace breakers or components during my lifetime.

Comment: Your power company usually has the last say of what panels you can use.  We could(but not allowed on here) recommend panels, but the power company have their own list of what panels they will allow.

Answer (score 1):

You **must** start with your utility to determine which types/models of meter main/panels are allowed. For a *separate* main panel from meter main, the meter main is the utility's choice and the "main" panel is your choice (anything UL or ETL listed). The "main" is because technically a big main panel with a 200A breaker and 30+ spaces, etc. that is *after* a meter main is a subpanel. But except for keeping grounds and neutrals separate (possibly requiring buying an extra ground bar) it makes no practical difference.

As noted many times here, a large panel is a must. That typically means for a 200A service at least **30** spaces. Not **circuits** but **spaces**. That's because tandem (half-size) breakers are generally limited in capacity and generally (but not 100%, some are available for some panels) not available with GFCI or AFCI.

As far as brands, Square D, Eaton and GE aren't about to disappear any time soon. They all have long history, with some of their current panels using the same breakers as panels still in service from decades ago. What your specs do mean is that you should go to the high-end offerings - Eaton CH (which I have - my electrician's favorite) rather than BR and Square D QO rather than Homeline. (I am not sure where GE fits into all of this - they seem somewhat lower-end, but at least several panels I checked have copper bus bars.)

While there are *some* large meter mains, using two separate panels - a small meter main and a *huge* "main" panel - outside will help in a few ways:

- Feeding large subpanels won't take space from your "main" panel (effectively increasing the total spaces available)
- Big "main" panels are cheap. Really. And they often include a bunch of "extra" breakers as part of a bundle. Since this will be right next to your meter main, it doesn't *have* to have a main breaker, but it can - depends on pricing.

So if you can find a 30 space or larger Siemens, Eaton CH, Square D QO, etc. meter main, great. If not (or even if you do find such an item), consider separate meter main and "main" panel.